# Trying to get a list from input (python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a list from the input function

```
programme = input('giving list')
#giving a list ['1','2','2']

print(programme)
noob = list(programme)
print(type(noob))
print(noob)
```

Here is the terminal answer

```
giving list['1','2','2']

['1','2','2']
<class 'list'>
['[', "'", '1', "'", ',', "'", '2', "'", ',', "'", '2', "'", ']']
```

is it possible to recover 'noob' variable like :

```
noob = ['1','2','2']
```

instead of `noob = ['[', "'", '1', "'", ',', "'", '2', "'", ',', "'", '2', "'", ']']`

Comment: User should just type: 1,2,2.  print(programme.split(',')) will be  ['1','2','2']

Comment: There is "ast.literal_eval()" for this.

Comment: Is there any specific format you would like to have the input? for example 1,2,3,4,5 or do you want to have multiple inputs each of them appended to a list?

Comment: micheal Bustcher you gaveme the correct answer. how can i make you as problem solver ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

```
import ast

def get_list_input(input_string):
    return ast.literal_eval(input(input_string))
```

Answer (score 0):

python input is always in string format. So you need to get entries on how  DarrylG suggested. Ask users to enter data in comma-separated or colon-separated.

You can also create a loop and ask user to enter the entries one by one. Append this data to a list. Keep a key to exit the input for loop. Like Enter "exit_this" to exit.